# Can't edit moodle password policy

Tags: php, moodle, moodle-api

I want to edit moodle's password policy  (I have admin account) but when i try to edit new  values and after that push button 
"Save changes"  it don't saves edited value and insted shows me old default values   i have moodle 3.5 and in it's  opensource code in (admin->category.php) i have found  code like this:
I am not experienced developer  but  from this code i found that admin user isn't allowed to edit settings at all

1. why this  logic is placed in this code (Is  it because password
   policy should't been edited or because of extra secuirity?)
2. If i make $adminediting  always true my admin account would be able
   to change settings?

   $adminediting = optional_param('adminedit', -1, PARAM_BOOL);

   ```
   if ($PAGE->user_allowed_editing() && $adminediting != -1) {
       $USER->editing = $adminediting;
   }
   if ($PAGE->user_allowed_editing()) {
       $url = clone($PAGE->url);
       if ($PAGE->user_is_editing()) {
           $caption = get_string('blockseditoff');
           $url->param('adminedit', 'off');
       } else {
           $caption = get_string('blocksediton');
           $url->param('adminedit', 'on');
       }
       $buttons = $OUTPUT->single_button($url, $caption, 'get');
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Admin editing is something related to 'turning editing mode on' for your LMS to make any changes. Admin authorized to do any modifications in LMS.

Check in database config table for your setting.